# Ruby Invoking Module Method On Extend

Tags: ruby, module

Given a basic ruby class and module, is there a way to call a method from the module as soon as an instance of the class is extended ?

```
class Dog 
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name 
  end 
end

module Speech
  def say_name
    puts @name
  end
  # call to method in module ?
  say_name
end

fido = Dog.new('fido')
fido.extend Speech    => *'fido'*
```

I am aware of the 'included' method that acts sort of like a callback when a module is included, but I was hoping for something similar for extend.

Comment: *"I am aware of the 'included' method that acts sort of like a callback when a module is included, but I was hoping for something similar for extend."* you mean like [`Module#extended`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-extended)?

Comment: yes... I guess Module#extended is what I was looking for . That's what I get for reading a blog before I read documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one trick using the method [`extend_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-extend_object).

> Extends the specified object by adding this module’s **constants** and **methods** (which are added as *singleton methods*). This is the callback method used by `Object#extend`.

```
class Dog 
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name 
  end 
end

module Speech
  def Speech.extend_object(o)
    super
    puts o.say_name
  end

  def say_name
    @name
  end
end

fido = Dog.new('fido')
fido.extend Speech # 'fido'
```